# Show that $\left\langle\alpha_A(I\cap J)\right\rangle \subset \left\langle\alpha_A(I)\right\rangle \cap \left\langle\alpha_A(J)\right\rangle $.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, linear-transformations

Let $\alpha_A: k[x_1,...,x_m]\rightarrow k[y_1,...,y_n]$ be a map defined by $\alpha_A(f)(y)=f(Ay)$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix.

Show that $\left\langle\alpha_A(I\cap J)\right\rangle \subset \left\langle\alpha_A(I)\right\rangle \cap \left\langle\alpha_A(J)\right\rangle $, with equality if $I\supset K$ or $J\supset K$ and $\alpha_A$ is onto, where $K=\ker(\alpha_A)$.

**My attempt**:

Let $f'\in \left\langle\alpha_A(I\cap J)\right\rangle$, then 
$$f'=\sum a_i\alpha_A(f_i)$$
where $f_i\in I\cap J$ and $a_i\in k[y_1,...,y_n]$. This is clearly in $\left\langle\alpha_A(I)\right\rangle \cap \left\langle\alpha_A(J)\right\rangle$ because by this equation $f'$ is in both $\left\langle\alpha_A(I)\right\rangle$ and $\left\langle\alpha_A(J)\right\rangle$.

The equality is where I have trouble with.

Suppose now $I\supset K$. Let $g'\in \left\langle\alpha_A(I)\right\rangle \cap \left\langle\alpha_A(J)\right\rangle $
$$g'=\sum a_i\alpha_A(g_i)=\sum b_j\alpha_A(h_j)$$
where $g_i\in I$, $h_j\in J$.

My thought is since $I\supset K$, I should use the first express, and try to write $g_i$ as $g_i+f_i\in J$, such that $f_i$ is in $K$. Then $g'$ would be in $\left\langle\alpha_A(I\cap J)\right\rangle$. But I couldn't find these $f_i$'s, and couldn't think of any other way to go around this.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This is becoming a pattern: the assumptions of the book are way too strong. One should be able to do this [the first part, at least] for any ring homomorphism $f\colon A \to B$ and ideals $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b} \subseteq A$. For the second you probably do need this matrix. Are the entries of $A$ in $k[x_1, \dots]$ or $k$, by the way?

Comment: @Hoot: Thank you again for your answer! In fact the book is trying to teach ideals and varieties without knowing much about commutative algebra. It is very well-written and I could do most of the problems without help. It's just until this chapter I felt a little beyond me since I don't have much background in commutative algebra. The entries of $A$ are in $k$. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Hoot: Any hint for the second part?

Comment: Well, I didn't give a hint for that since it wasn't immediately clear to me how to do it. I may be wrong about the hypotheses being necessary. Will have to find time to think about it later.

Comment: Again you missed the condition "$\alpha_A$ onto" for having equality.

Comment: @user26857: Maybe I should have looked at their errors and corrections from their website. But then for this problem, how could you use "onto" to solve it?

Comment: I've posted an answer which shows that your questions have nothing to do with the particular map and rings you consider. I have no idea why Cox and al. have chosen to formulate that exercises in this way.

Comment: @user26857: It kind of suits me (or people like me) who wants to learn something about ideals and varieties without knowing much about commutative algebra.

Comment: Ah, that's why it wasn't obvious. Thanks for the correction @user26857. I agree with you that the hypotheses are strange. I'm all for specializing problems to make things easier for beginners but here (i) it takes practically no extra work to introduce the general case and (ii) the specificity does not help you in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $\alpha:A\to B$ be a surjective ring homomorphism, $K=\ker\alpha$, and $I,J\subset A$ be ideals with the property $I\supseteq K$ or $J\supseteq K$. Then $(I\cap J)^e=I^e\cap J^e$, where $I^e=\langle\alpha(I)\rangle$.

We prove "$\supseteq$".
Let $b\in I^e\cap J^e$. Then $b=\sum_{i=1}^r b_i\alpha(a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^rb_i'\alpha(a_i')$ with $b_i,b_i'\in B$, $a_i\in I$, and $a_i'\in J$. Since $\alpha$ is surjective there exist $u_i,u_i'\in A$ such that $\alpha(u_i)=b_i$ and $\alpha(u_i')=b_i'$. Thus $b=\sum_{i=1}^r\alpha(u_i)\alpha(a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^r\alpha(u_i')\alpha(a_i')$. We then have $\sum_{i=1}^ru_ia_i-\sum_{i=1}^ru_i'a_i'\in K$. Suppose $J\supseteq K$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^ru_ia_i-\sum_{i=1}^ru_i'a_i'\in J$, and therefore $\sum_{i=1}^ru_ia_i\in I\cap J$. Now conclude that $b\in (I\cap J)^e$.

Comment: I see. I thought it has something to do with the matrix multiplication. Thank you very much! And by the way, in your second line of proof, you meant $b=\sum_{i=1}^r b_i\alpha(a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^rb_i'\alpha(a_i')$.

Comment: Now all should be clear.