# Show that $\alpha_A^{-1}(I'+J')=\alpha_A^{-1}(I')+\alpha_A^{-1}(J')$, where $I',J'$ are ideals and $\alpha_A$ is a surjective ring homomorphism.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $\alpha_A: k[x_1,...,x_m]\rightarrow k[y_1,...,y_n]$ be a map defined by $\alpha_A(f)(y)=f(Ay)$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ constant matrix. Let $I',J'$ be ideals in $k[y_1,...,y_n]$.
>
> Show that $\alpha_A^{-1}(I'+J')=\alpha_A^{-1}(I')+\alpha_A^{-1}(J')$ if $\alpha_A$ is onto.

This exercise is a continuation of my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329066/show-that-left-langle-alpha-ai-cap-j-right-rangle-subset-left-langle-alpha).

**My attempt:**
The reverse direction is very easy. Let $f\in \alpha_A^{-1}(I')+\alpha_A^{-1}(J')$. Then $f=g+h$, such that $\alpha_A(g)\in I'$ and $\alpha_A(h)\in J'$. So $\alpha_A(f)=\alpha_A(g)+\alpha_A(h)\in I'+J'$. Thus $f\in \alpha_A^{-1}(I'+J')$, which shows $\alpha_A^{-1}(I'+J')\supset \alpha_A^{-1}(I')+\alpha_A^{-1}(J')$.

I am stuck at the other direction.

Let $f\in \alpha_A^{-1}(I'+J')$. Then $\alpha_A(f)\in I'+J'$. So we can write $\alpha_A(f)=ag'+bh'$ such that $g'\in I', h'\in J'$, and $a,b\in k[y_1,...,y_n]$. I know in general, since the map might not be surjective, this direction is not true. But maybe the matrix $A$ serves some role here to make up that.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: "*constant matrix*" means $A\in M_{m\times n}(k)$? I also don't understand how $\alpha_A$ is defined. It must be something like this: $\alpha_A(f(x_1,\dots,x_m))=\text{polynomial}(y_1,\dots,y_n)$; $\alpha_A(f)(y)$ has no meaning to me. For instance, what is $\alpha_A(x_1)$?

Comment: @user26857: Thank you for your response! Yes, $A\in M_{m\times n}(k)$. For example, if $A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, then $\alpha_A$ maps $f(x_1,x_2)$ to $f(y,y)$.

Comment: And if $A=\left(\begin{array}{c}3\\2\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: @user26857: I guess that is a better example. Then $f(x_1,x_2)=f(3y,2y)$.

Comment: It doesn't look like a matrix multiplication. (I've expected to multiply $A$ by the vector $(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ somehow.) What if $A=\left(\begin{array}{c}3&4\\2&5\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: @user26857: It is $\vec{x}=A\vec{y}$. So in this case, $f(x_1,x_2)=f(3y_1+4y_2, 2y_1+5y_2)$.

Comment: I think it's good to include as much information as you can. Of course it's wise to put the most interesting parts at the top but if people don't want to read the rest then they won't. Question titles like "Cox, Little, O'Shea - Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms - Exercise 3.44" are of course horrible. I'm not suggesting that. Anyway, again, the proof has very little to do with polynomial rings.

Comment: Also, it would be good for you to remember which of these inclusions always holds, even if the map is not surjective.

Comment: @Hoot: Thank you. I'll try to remember. Problem is there are too many identities to remember. :)

Comment: Maybe "remember" isn't the right word -- there's a list of 15 or so identities of this sort in chapter 1 of Atiyah-Macdonald and I doubt anyone sits down and memorizes them. It's more about keeping in mind that some relationship will hold in general and that if you fiddle around with the objects then it's usually obvious what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user26857's help, here is my answer for the direction $\subset$:

Let $f\in \alpha_A^{-1}(I'+J')$. Then $\alpha_A(f)=g'+h'$ for some $g'\in I', h'\in J'$.

Since $\alpha_A$ is onto, there exists $g\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $\alpha_A(g)=g'$.

We then have $\alpha_A(f-g)=\alpha_A(f)-\alpha_A(g)=h'\in J'$. Hence $f=g+(f-g)\in \alpha_A^{-1}(I')+\alpha_A^{-1}(J')$.